NextFont variable properties unable to be applied to CSS global using var()
// font.ts file

import { Quicksand, Syncopate } from 'next/font/google';

export const quickSandRegular = Quicksand({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-quicksand-reg',
  weight: '400',
  display: 'swap',
});
export const quickSandSmBold = Quicksand({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-quicksand-smbold',
  weight: '600',
  display: 'swap',
});

export const syncopateRegular = Syncopate({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-syncopate-reg',
  weight: '400',
  display: 'swap',
});

export const syncopateBold = Syncopate({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-syncopate-bold',
  weight: '700',
  display: 'swap',
});


//layout.tsx file

import {
  quickSandRegular,
  quickSandSmBold,
  syncopateBold,
  syncopateRegular,
} from '@/lib/fonts';

export default function RootLayout({
 children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${[
          syncopateRegular.variable,
          syncopateBold.variable,
          quickSandRegular.variable,
          quickSandSmBold.variable,
        ]}  `}
      >
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

// global.css file
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .card {
    & .header {
      font-family: var(--font-syncopate-reg);
      @apply center;
    }
  }
}

// page.tsx file

export default function CustomerList() { 
  return (<Card className="card">
        <CardHeader>
          <CardTitle className="header">RIMIX</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
      </Card>)
}

I tried using NextFont's variable in my CSS file, but it didn't manage to change the font family.
So according to NextJs documentation, I could change the font family of a text by specifying inside my css file using the variable name defined.
const syncopateRegular = Syncopate({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-syncopate-reg', /** using this in global css file in var() */
  weight: '400',
  display: 'swap',
});

But my text's font still remained the same.
Initially I thought the issue was because I have mistakenly used .className instead of .variable suffix for the fonts inserted into Root Layout, but that wasn't the case.

is the final rendered <body> receiving the expected class names?

I managed to solve this, taking a closer look at the documentation I realized I need to add the .variable classNames one by one and not put them all into an array.


<body
        className={`${syncopateRegular.variable} ${syncopateBold.variable} ${quickSandRegular.variable} ${quickSandSmBold.variable}  `}
      >
        {children}
      </body>



